# Compactation in CouchDB. How to preserve selected revisions

Tags: database, couchdb

Is there a way to manage which documents' older versions might be removed or not during compactation process?

For instance a magic metadata field in a doc: _do_not_compact:true, when the field is in the document version then the version won't be comapcated?

I would like to use versioning of the docs in couchdb to make some time-machine-like features in my app, giving users functionality to see data in the previous versions.

Answer (score 4):

Older revisions are not guaranteed to be available and should not be used as a way to provide document versioning. They are present primarily to aid in efficient replication for multiple CouchDB nodes (in a highly used system, some nodes wouldn't have all versions of documents for example).

If you want to version documents, you should introduce your own schema/system.